# How can I make this Sticky Header jQuery header work?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get a sticky header to work like when I scroll down, the header will disappear and when I start to scroll up the header will reappear.

This is my jQuery:

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $(".header-top").outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $(".header-top").removeClass("sticky-header--top").addClass("sticky-header--hidden");
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $(".header-top").removeClass("sticky-header--hidden").addClass("sticky-header--fixed");
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

I am trying to make it add and remove classes from this div:

```
<div class="header__top sticky-header sticky-header--top" sticky-header="">
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the div by selecting the class. I've tried finding it with id but with no result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `$('.header-top')` but your element has class `header__top` so use `$('.header__top')`

Also, what is `$(this)` in your function? Maybe this should be `$(window)` or something else. Try and alert your variable after getting scrolltop to see if it actually has a value.

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked it, but earlier I tried using an ID to get the item but without any luck. Also now, after I corrected my code no classes are added or removed.

Comment: Added another possible issue. Try that?

Comment: Here's a link to the article from where I borrowed the code. https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c#.usu1pfv4v Maybe this is easier for you to analyze.

Comment: Okay. There was actually an typo in the jQuery loading script, since this is hosted on my computer. However, the code doesn't operate exactly as I want. The header will disappear when scrolling down the first time, but not if I start scrolling down midways when I am midways on the page. So basicly, I want it to disappear everytime I scroll down. If you would like to give me a suggestion on how I can accomplish this I would be very grateful. //FIXED